# How to use a HuggingFace Dataset to fine-tune a spaCy pipeline

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition, huggingface

I am trying to fine-tune a spaCy pipeline, [en_core_web_sm](https://spacy.io/models/en#en_core_web_sm), in particular its NER (Named Entity Recognition) component. I found this [dataset](https://huggingface.co/datasets/tner/mit_restaurant) on HuggingFace which is perfect for the task I want to do it.

I cloned the git repository, with the corresponding `json` files. Then I tried to use `python -m spacy convert mit_restaurant/dataset mit_restaurant/spacy`, which should [Convert files into spaCy’s binary training data format, a serialized DocBin, for use with the train command](https://spacy.io/api/cli#convert).

However I get this error:

```
NotOpenSSLWarning: urllib3 v2 only supports OpenSSL 1.1.1+, currently the 'ssl' module is compiled with 'LibreSSL 2.8.3'. See: https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/3020
  warnings.warn(
✔ Generated output file (0 documents):
mit_restaurant/spacy/label.spacy
✔ Generated output file (0 documents):
mit_restaurant/spacy/test.spacy
✔ Generated output file (0 documents):
mit_restaurant/spacy/train.spacy
✔ Generated output file (0 documents):
mit_restaurant/spacy/valid.spacy
```

I expected the script to be able to convert the documents, but it does not seem to recognise them.
Are there any intermediate preprocessing steps I need to carry out on the hugging face dataset to get it ready for spaCy training?

Comment: `spacy convert` can only handle the formats documented here: https://spacy.io/api/cli#converters. You would need to convert this format to `Doc` objects similar to: https://github.com/explosion/projects/blob/83fb5e4cc40aea9321f4875a46db505deb762c31/pipelines/ner_demo/scripts/convert.py except that you'd want to use `Doc(words=, ents=)` instead of `Doc.char_span`.